# What does a successful NecTAR application look like

Tags: computer-science, application, australia

This is quite specific question, though, it specificness is largely related to the fact it can only be answered by someone with experience with computational research in Australia.

[NeCTAR](https://www.nectar.org.au/) grants Cloud computing resources, in the form of VM's to Australian researchers.

To apply for resources there are several fields.

The [allocation documentation](https://support.rc.nectar.org.au/docs/allocations) is quite sparse on recommendations for what they are to contain.

The most significant of which is the *"Research use case"* which has the description:

> **Research use case** [Form Box Here] Note: A short write up on how you intend to use your cloud instances will help us in our decision making.

It's not much to go on.

The box is quite small though it is expandable.
I'm not sure how much to write. It doesn't support rich text or any kind of markup. I am wondering if I should reference my statements (seems awkward without rich text).

Or if I should be describing other avenues of getting compute power attempted etc.

[The documentation](https://support.rc.nectar.org.au/docs/allocations) does note:

> If there are any issues with your request, we will get in touch with you.
>   You may be asked to provide more detail about your research or to clarify your technical requirements.

So perhaps what I write the first time does not even matter,
since they will just ask for clarification until I have appropriate amounts of information?

I am really looking for an example of an application that someone has done successfully in the past. Just to get an idea of what it would be like.

Comment: My application was successful. I might actually check to see if there is any issue with me just uploading the whole thing as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any personal experience with NeCTAR; maybe someone who does will chime in.

But if it's anything like the US and EU analogues I have worked with (e.g. PlanetLab, GENI, OneLab), this information is used mainly

- to collect information about how the system is being used (e.g. to report back to funding source), and
- to filter requests that are clearly ineligible (e.g. "I want to host my personal website on your cloud"),

not because they reject some serious, eligible requests based on application details.

If that's the case here, too, you really don't need to worry too much about what you write. Something of the form

> My research is on X. I will use the system in order to do Y.

should suffice. (If you happen to have a project website, adding a link to it is also nice.)